# Solver 'SCIPY' failed in CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, cvxpy

I am solving LP problem with CVXPY and Scipy for different number of variables. It worked fine for smaller number of variables but returned an error when I increased one number of variables.

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                    v1.1.17                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: Your problem has 8760 variables, 4 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=SCIPY).
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> SCIPY
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:52 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:53 PM: Applying reduction SCIPY
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:53 PM: Finished problem compilation (took 2.918e-01 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Dec 01 06:09:53 PM: Invoking solver SCIPY  to obtain a solution.
Solver terminated with message: An optimal solution to the scaled model was found but was HiGHS Status Code 0: HighsModelStatusNOTSET in the unscaled model. For more information run with the option `disp: True`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Novix\Desktop\Optimization Course\Jobs.py", line 71, in <module>
    prob.solve(solver=cvx.SCIPY, scipy_options={"method": "highs"},verbose=True,disp= True)
  File "C:\Users\Novix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 472, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Novix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 978, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, solving_chain, inverse_data)
  File "C:\Users\Novix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 1300, in unpack_results
    raise error.SolverError(
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCIPY' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
```

Aditional info DISP = TRUE

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Dec 02 11:55:17 AM: Invoking solver SCIPY  to obtain a solution.
C:\Users\Novix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog_highs.py:374: OptimizeWarning: Option "message_level" is "TrueTrueTrueTrue", but only values in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} are allowed. Using default: 4.
  res = _highs_wrapper(c, A.indptr, A.indices, A.data, lhs, rhs,
Presolve : Reductions: rows 4745(-52560); columns 4382(-21898); elements 189456(-104304)
INFO   : Solving the presolved LP
INFO   : Scaling: Improvement factor is 84.28 >= 1 so scale LP
INFO   : Basis condition estimate of           1 is within the tolerance of 1e+14
WARNING: Number of OMP threads available = 0 < 1 = Number of HiGHS threads to be used: Parallel performance will be less than anticipated
INFO   : Using dual simplex solver - serial
       Iteration        Objective     Infeasibilities num(sum)
DuPh2          0     0.0000000000e+00 Pr: 365(4.75632e+09)
DuPh2        196     6.2405594583e+09 Pr: 365(4.75632e+09); Du: 0(3.75857e-08)
DuPh2        398     1.0875331763e+10 Pr: 2170(3.27233e+10); Du: 0(4.74177e-07)
DuPh2        486     1.0875333519e+10 Pr: 2228(2.4751e+10); Du: 0(4.36591e-07)
DuPh2        586     1.0875334791e+10 Pr: 758(3.67802e+09); Du: 0(3.40088e-07)
DuPh2        694     1.0875336442e+10 Pr: 444(1.11427e+09); Du: 0(1.30185e-07)
DuPh2        869     1.0876239127e+10 Pr: 1064(7.89964e+09); Du: 0(3.70512e-07)
DuPh2       1010     1.0892424332e+10 Pr: 2138(1.56553e+11); Du: 0(3.17368e-07)
DuPh2       1203     1.0895512647e+10 Pr: 2284(5.73842e+09); Du: 0(1.52299e-07)
DuPh2       1350     1.0905412252e+10 Pr: 925(2.32193e+09); Du: 0(1.52299e-07)
DuPh2       1498     1.0916326192e+10 Pr: 2080(2.25197e+09); Du: 0(2.08311e-07)
DuPh2       1659     1.0925159994e+10 Pr: 230(2.52726e+08); Du: 0(1.82972e-07)
DuPh2       1805     1.0930178768e+10 Pr: 2097(5.25322e+08); Du: 0(2.33463e-07)
DuPh2       1983     1.0933241880e+10 Pr: 446(2.00014e+08); Du: 0(2.33463e-07)
DuPh2       2132     1.0934288724e+10 Pr: 57(1.57648e+06); Du: 0(3.23741e-07)
DuPh2       2142     1.0934289941e+10 Pr: 0(1.06869e-07); Du: 0(3.23741e-07)
DuPh2       2142     1.0934235826e+10 Pr: 0(1.06869e-07); Du: 2(1.125e-05)
PrPh2       2142     1.0934235826e+10 Pr: 0(1.06869e-07); Du: 2(1.125e-05)
PrPh2       2144     1.0934235826e+10 Pr: 0(1.06869e-07); Du: 0(9.23706e-14)
INFO   : Dual simplex iterations [Ph1 0; Ph2 2142; Pr 2] Total 2144
INFO   : Solving the original LP from the solution after postsolve
INFO   : Scaling: Improvement factor is 46.01 >= 1 so scale LP
INFO   : Basis condition estimate of   6.291e+06 is within the tolerance of 1e+14
INFO   : Have 12 primal and 0 dual unscaled infeasibilities
INFO   : Possibly re-solve with feasibility tolerances of 2.5e-08 primal and 1e-07 dual
INFO   : Not re-solving with refined tolerances
Postsolve  : 0
Time       :     2.32
Time Pre   :     0.78
Time PreLP :     0.49
Time PostLP:     0.18
For LP                 : Presolve     0.78 ( 33%): Solve presolved LP     0.49 ( 21%): Solve original LP     0.18 (  7%)
Strange: Solve time = 2.32403; Sum times = 1.45123: relative difference = 0.375553
Solver terminated with message: An optimal solution to the scaled model was found but was HiGHS Status Code 0: HighsModelStatusNOTSET in the unscaled model. For more information run with the option `disp: True`.
```

I tried with solver ECOS, but it obtain an "optimal_inaccurate"

Do anyone know why scipy fail?

Comment: The error message suggests to "solve with verbose=True for more information" - have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, the code shows with verbose=True!

Comment: Sounds like numerical problems of some sort. Do you have any more log output from any solver with verbose=True? Here there is only cvxpy log but almost no solver log at all.

Comment: I edited the post with some extra information that the solver shows when i added an extra parametrer 'disp':'True' in scipy settings

Comment: I am no expert in the scipy log output but an objective value of order 1e+10 is very likely to cause all kinds of numerical problems to any solver.